# 2sxc Blog App show year in URL of detail page

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

I'm using the default Blog App, by default the detail page url starts with /post/*
However, i also like the PublicationMoment Year to show as well in the URL. So for example if the post was published in year 2017 the detail page will have the year in the URL.

domain/blog/post/**2017**/post-url

example

```
http://2sxc.org/en/blog/post/2017/upgrading-to-2sxc-9-3-requires-2sxc-7
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is no problem at all. In the list view the link to the details is generated, ad you can basically add more stuff as you need it. DNN auto-converts pairs of values into request-variables, so

`/post/xyz`
is converted to
`post=xyz`

`/post/2017/xyz`
is converted to
`post=2017` -> you don't want this!

`/year/2017/post/xyz`
converts to
`year=2017`
`post=xyz`
--> so this is probably what you want

Comment: Did this answer your question? if yes, please mark it as such to help future users.